# R error: Error in derivePolygons(data, lng, lat, missing(lng), missing(lat), "addPolygons") :

Tags: r, leaflet

I'm trying to colour plot the "AveragePlot" data over a map but I keep getting the error:
Error in derivePolygons(data, lng, lat, missing(lng), missing(lat), "addPolygons") :

I have been trying to fix this for hours but I have not been able to find a solution. Any help would be highly appreciated.

My code:

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(leaflet)
library(readr)
library(tidyr)

urlfile="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/InstituteForGlobalEcology/Coral-bleaching-a-global-analysis-of-the-past-two-decades/master/Reef_Check_with_cortad_variables_with_annual_rate_of_SST_change.csv "


mydata<-read_csv(url(urlfile))


qpal <- colorNumeric(palette="RdYlGn", mydata$Average_bleaching, na.color = "#808080")

mydata$Longitude.Degrees <- as.numeric(mydata$Longitude.Degrees )
mydata$Latitude.Degrees <- as.numeric(mydata$Latitude.Degrees )

m <- leaflet() %>% addTiles()  %>% addCircleMarkers(data=mydata, lat=~Latitude.Degrees, lng=~Longitude.Degrees, color=~Average_bleaching)
```

I have tried making the data using polygons according the following code.

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(leaflet)
library(readr)
library(tidyr)

urlfile="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/InstituteForGlobalEcology/Coral-bleaching-a-global-analysis-of-the-past-two-decades/master/Reef_Check_with_cortad_variables_with_annual_rate_of_SST_change.csv "


mydata<-read_csv(url(urlfile))

qpal <- colorNumeric(palette="RdYlGn", mydata$Average_bleaching, na.color = "#808080")

mydata$Longitude.Degrees <- as.numeric(mydata$Longitude.Degrees )
mydata$Latitude.Degrees <- as.numeric(mydata$Latitude.Degrees )

data.sp <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(mydata[, c(54,55)], mydata[, -c(54,55)])


m <- leaflet() %>% addTiles()  %>% addCircleMarkers(data=data.sp, lat=~Latitude.Degrees, lng=~Longitude.Degrees, color=~Average_bleaching)
```

I really am unsure as to why Im getting this error. This code is reproducible btw as the link is public iirc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Does this get you closer to what you want?

```
                      color=~qpal(Average_bleaching)
```

Comment: Hi Russ, good pick up but Unfortunately no. Following that, I get this error: 
"Error in eval(f[[2]], metaData(data), environment(f)) : 
object 'Longitude.Degrees' not found"

Comment: That's weird because the code works for me. :D Are you sure the earlier steps are working? There's also a space between the end of the url and the closing the quote